# Construction of linear mixed model (using R)

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, multicollinearity

I would like to use Lineal Mixed model to see if the treatments I applied to some soil changed significantly their CO2 fluxes.

I have 2 temperature (t1, t2) and 3 inundation (w0,w1,w2), resulting in 6 treatments (table 1). For each of my treatment I have ten replicates. To increase my number of replicates, I sampled 5 times each of my pot (Repeated measurements with Date of sampling). Here is my experimental design[image: Experimental design]

**I have used Lineal Mixed model to answer my question, but my model seems to not meet the assumption of no collinearity - I have strips lines (see last figure). Is it due to the construction of my model? or should I use another test? -I have repeated measurements).**

Here are some more explanation about how I constructed my model and checked for assumption:

**How I constructed my Lineal Mixed model:**

**1. I load my dataframe** , where PID reflect the repeated measurement. I enter PID, Temperature and Flooding  as factorial variables and Fluxes has numerical
[image]

**2. I construct my model** with temperature and Flooding as fixed effect, and as random error, I put temperature and flooding (because they are crossed) and PID, because I have repeated measurement. My code looks like:

```
TemperatureFlooding.model = lmer (Fluxes ~ Temperature*Flooding + (1|PID) + (1|Temperature) + (1|Flooding), data = BETADecompositioncsv )
```

My results are: 
[image]

**3. likelihood ration test:** I want to see if  inundation, temperature and temperature*inundation have a significant influence on CO2 emission. I use the likelihood ratio test for that. As illustration my code looks like that:

```
Temperature.modelNULL = lmer (Fluxes ~ Temperature + (1|PID) + (1|Temperature) + (1|Flooding),data = BETADecompositioncsv, REML=FALSE)

TemperatureFlooding.modelFULL = lmer (Fluxes ~ Temperature*Flooding + (1|PID) + (1|Temperature) + (1|Flooding),
                        data = BETADecompositioncsv, REML=FALSE)

anova(Flooding.modelNULL,TemperatureFlooding.modelFULL)
```

--> For all I found a p value <0.05

**3. I check the first assumption** of the model: collinearity
For that I do a residual plot with the following code:

```
plot(fitted(TemperatureFlooding.model),residuals(TemperatureFlooding.model))
```

and I get that: 
[image]

**--> my model seems to not meet the assumption of no collinearity - I have strips lines (see top figure). Is it due to the construction of my model? or should I use another test? -I have repeated measurements.**

---

Comment: Could you explain what this "assumption of collinearity" is?

Comment: Sorry, the way I wrote it was unclear. I mean, it should have absence of collinearity .Thanks for pointing that out, I will try to edit

Comment: OK, but why are you focusing on this?  There are extremely few regression procedures (if any at all) that require the absence of collinearity!  Moreover, the plot you show is completely irrelevant for an analysis of collinearity, which leads me to suspect you might be using "collinearity" in place of some other term with a completely different meaning.  Perhaps you're trying to ask about homoscedasticity?

Comment: Thanks whuber. Why the absence of collinearity is not required? - See the assumption of the test in this tutorial page 28: http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/bw_LME_tutorial2.pdf

Comment: That tutorial mentions collinearity exactly once, and merely states (vaguely) you need to "worry" about it.  It does not state or even imply that lack of collinearity is an assumption of the model.  Yes, when you are interested in p-values you will want to check that they are not heavily influenced by near-collinearity of variables, but that's about as far as it goes.

Comment: Thanks Whuber for the precision. Do you have any reference for the GLMM assumption that I could check? and is overall my model well constructed? thanks for your help

Comment: There's a whiff of heteroscedasticity in the residuals, suggesting that using the square root or logarithm of the flux (rather than the flux itself) could produce substantial improvement.

Comment: Thanks - I will give a try with a log10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is not a *generalized* linear mixed model. It is simply a linear mixed model.

Second, notice from your output that your model has a singular fit. Often this indicates that the model is over-fitted with respect to the random effects. In other words the data do not support the random effects structure that you have specified. You are fitting random intercepts for `Temperature` and `flooding`, yet you have only 2 and 3 levels of these. The software assumes that the random effects are normally distributed, so it is trying to estimate variances for two normally distributed variables where there is only 2 and 3 observations for them. You should not do this.

You are also specifying both of these variables as fixed effects. They should be one, or the other, not both. We have already established that there are insufficient levels of each of them to warrant fitting them as random effects, and you also appear to be interested in the fixed effects of each, and their interaction. It is hardly surprising that these data do not support such a model. A good place to start would be with this model:

```
lmer(Fluxes ~ Temperature*Flooding + (1|PID) ...)
```

If this produces sensible output, then, subject to your *a priori* hypothesis, you may wish to allow the fixed effects for `Temperature`, `Flooding` and their interaction to vary by `PID` by estimating random slopes.

Regarding collinearity, unless the variables are perfectly correlated, or almost so, this will not be a problem. Some correlation between covariates is quite normal, and to be expected. Having said that, as per @whuber's comments, your plot has nothing to do with collinearity.

Comment: Thanks Robert! So, if I understood well, the crossing of my factor should not be included as a random error, isn'it? - because of the reduced number of variable (2 and 3). Overalll, I should only include time as a random error (which weirdly have a variance of 0 in the random effect)- I will try to rerun with only PID as random error. Thanks

Comment: @Novice_stat Yes, but the zero variance for `PID` might be caused by the singular fit. It is not only the number of levels (2 and 3), but also that you want to estimate fixed effects for them. You should not do both.

Comment: I corrected the model as " lmer (log10(Fluxes) ~ Temperature*Flooding + (1|PID) , data = Decompositioncsv ) "; but I still have a singular fit and still have a variance of 0 for the PID; Is it due to a wrong coding of the PID? I numbered each pot to 1 to 10, for each treatment (see point 1. figure).

Comment: @Novice_stat it shouldn't have anything to do with the coding. Can you post a link to the whole dataset? Otherwise it is close to impossible to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I don't know how to post the data in stack, here they are: https://we.tl/t-fxXB3eEumG

Comment: @Novice_stat I don't get a singular fit. Which version of `lme4` are you using ? The random intercepts have very small variance, so you probably don't need them and you can just use `lm()` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert! I have the 1.1-21 version (I think).

Comment: @Novice_stat I have reproduced that problem. This means that the variance of the random intercept is zero. Just use `lm()`. If you the variance should be greater than zero then please ask a new question about it.

Comment: I think I found the problem, it is the column that I used for random error, I should use Date. I did the lm model with Date as fixed effect and Date had a significant effect. Instead of using PID as random error in the mixed model, I used Date and it seems that Date as an effect! is the coding for Date correct for lmer model?

Comment: @Novice_stat Yes, you can use Date as a random effect instead of `PID`, and that seems to make more sense. Can you explain what `PID` is ?

Comment: It was the identification of each soil pot. It used to express that they were repeatitively sampled.